# UIAlertView without Cancel Button?

Tags: iphone, button, uialertview, cancel-button

I am trying to create a UIAlertView that has 3 options and no "cancel" button, but when I do this, it always styles "Button 3" as a cancel button. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
UIAlertView *alertView= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select One" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2", @"Button3", nil];
```

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like there isn't a way surprisingly. I'm still playing with it, but it seems that the cancel button defaults to one of the other buttons.

Comment: At this point I have gone with an Action Sheet. Not really the way I want to do it, so if anyone knows how to make the Alert View work, please feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456675/change-position-of-cancel-button-in-uialertview) is a post about how to change the position of the cancel button. Also, if you have only 1 button in the `UIAlertView`, then setting:

```
_alertView.cancelButtonIndex = -1;
```

Will make the button appear as a non-cancel type button. As far as I can tell though, once you have more than 1 button, the `UIAlertView` forces the last button to be the cancel button. Looking through the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) may give you a clue about how to set the properties up to achieve this, but I'm not too sure. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 8):

I did differently, passing `cancelButtonTitle` argument as `nil`.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                           message:@"Message here"
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```