# How to set identical appeareance to buttons for an UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, ipad

By default, a `UIAlertView` with two buttons has different alpha for each button.

Is there a way to make them look identical with **different text**, without subclassing `UIAlertView`, or making a custom alert view?

Here is what i used:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:  
                     kAlertTitleOrderType message:kAlertMessageOrderType delegate:delegate
                     cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Collection", @"Delivery", nil];
```

[image]

Comment: I nuked my answer as it turned out to be wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250360/uialertview-without-cancel-button for more. It looks like you might have to roll your own! Interestingly, this behaviour is "fixed" in iOS 7 (i.e. cancel buttons are optional, and if you don't have them, all the buttons render identically), so it might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it seems I have to use a custom alertView.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `cancel` button to `nil` when calling `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` then no cancel button will be added (this is the one that looks different). You can then add other buttons as you require.

Comment: Doesn't work. Here is my line: 
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: kAlertTitleOrderType message:kAlertMessageOrderType delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Collection", @"Delivery", nil];

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the result you see on screen?

Comment: I just uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: Check the value of `cancelButtonIndex`. If it's `0`, set it to `-1`. If it's `-1`, I guess you'll need to subclass / tamper with subviews / use a custom view.